# InvalidSelectorError while using the properties file to get the Locators

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, properties

I am using Selenium Webdriver with TestNG.
I have kept the details of all the locators in a separate properties file.
When I try to reference the locators in my Java Code, I am getting the following error in the logs

> InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression "/html/body/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/a/b" because of
>   the following error: TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to
>   return the specified type.

Please find the code below :

```
@Test(priority=1)

public void testLoginOnFirstPage() {

      try {
          log.debug("Test#1 -  Login on the Home page ");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          loginButtonHomePage=By.xpath(prop.getProperty("login.button.homePage.xpath"));
          driver.findElement(loginButtonHomePage).click();
          Assert.assertTrue(true,"Login button clicked successsfully");
          log.debug("Test#1----------------------Login on the Home Page -----------------Passed");
      }

      catch(Exception e) {
          Assert.assertFalse(false,"Error while clicking on the Login button on the first page");
          log.error(e);
          log.debug("Test#1----------------------Login on the Home Page ----------------Failed");
         }
}
```

The property value is fetched properly. I have tried printing its value on the console.
It shows up like > By.xpath : "xpathexpression"

The code runs without any errors when I pass the xpath value without using the properties file.

Please help.

Comment: what you got from the properties file might be wrong. Properties file should not return By.xpath : "xpathexpression". It should just return "xpathexpression"

Comment: I would suggest you look into using the page object model instead of a properties file. I think it's much easier to use and is more organized.

Comment: I think the problem is in your xpath: you are trying to select bold text inside the link and click on it, while you should be clicking on a link, i.e. `<a>` itself.

Comment: @Kiril S : Thanks Kiril. But I am able to click the link with the same xpath , when I used the xpath expression to click on the link. The error occured when I used the properties file to pass the xpath expression.